Inconsistent Python import behaviour with subdirectories
When splitting my python code into simple modules and putting them in a subdirectory, I see seemingly inconsistent behaviour that I was not able to solve by adding an __init__.py file in the module. I am also unable to understand why things not seem to work consistently. Please explain or point to documentation where this "logic" is explained:
I have the following file structure:
a.py
module/b.py
module/c.py

The files contain the following contents:
a.py:
from module.b import hello

hello()

b.py:
from c import helloworld

def hello():
    helloworld()

hello()

c.py:
def helloworld():
    print("Hello world")

When I run b.py everything works:
# cd module/
# python b.py
Hello world

But when I run a.py from the parent directory suddenly python does not know where to find c.py:
# python a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python-playground/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module.b import hello
  File "python-playground/module/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from c import helloworld
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'c'

How can I make it so that I can run both module/b.py and a.py without Python complaining about imports without making my code too complicated?

Update: It seems that I can add sys.path.insert(0, 'module') to a.py to make this work. That would solve my problem for now, but I still think it is a bit confusing.

Do not touch sys.path!

Projects have usually one entry point located at the top directory (your a.py). Are you sure you need to directly execute b.py? Sounds like a badly structured code.

Do not touch sys.path, even if it sounds tempting and an easy fix – it will lead into pain and confusion down the line.
Your structure should be
a.py
module/__init__.py
module/b.py
module/c.py

so module becomes a (confusingly-named) package.
Then, imports within the package, e.g. module/b.py, should be either

from module import c
from . import c
from .c import some_name

and outside the module package, they would be

from module import c
from module.c import some_name

Finally, if there is a script that should be executable within module, such as module/show_bees.py,
from module.b import bee_movie

def main():
    print(bee_movie())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

you would invoke it with python -m module.show_bees.

Yes - try to add the __init__.py to each python "module", which is called a package. This is python-specific and flags the directory as package.

try to modify b.py as follows
from module.c import helloworld

